# A few questions on HTTPS encryption

Tags: encryption, https, key

I have a couple of questions about HTTPS encryption:

1. What is the bitsize of the keys used? Is it standardised? (I could not find this information searching the web.)
2. Can the keys generated for the key length start with a zero, or would this key be counted as a n - 1 bit key?

Comment: The SSL page on wikipedia doesn't tell me if the key length is standardised for HTTPS, nor does it tell me if the key can start with a zero.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security or cryptography and doesn't include a programming problem.

Comment: I just clicked the ask a question button. If it's "off-topic" here, could I request for the thread be moved to the appropriate place, instead of deleted or closed?

Answer (score 0):

During the initial handshake client and server agree among other things to an algorithm for symetric encryption. Keysize depends on the algorithm, e.g. AES128 is 128 bit, AES256 256 bit, DES 56 bit  etc. 
The key itself is random, which also means that it can start with 0. If you would restrict the initial bit to 1, you would effectively leave one bit less for the random bits.